# Allow IP range through linux firewall

Tags: linux, security, firewall, csf

I need to set up a rule to allow ALL outgoing UDP connections on my VPS. I am not sure what I should be using. I have tried: udp:out:d=1_9000:d=* in my csf.allow but its not working (and it was a guess on all accounts).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: I have tried: `udp:out:d=1_9000:d=IPHERE` and it works when I specify the IP. I have tried *, ? and ALL for the IP but can't get it to work will all or even a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok managed to sort it: `udp:out:d=1_9000:d=0.0.0.0/0`